# XSLT - for each with multiple lists

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML

```
<ListA>
    <item index="0">Test 1</item>
    <item index="1">Test 2</item>
    <item index="2">Test 3</item>
</ListA>
<ListB>
    <item index="0">100</item>
    <item index="1">200</item>
    <item index="2">300</item>
</ListB>
```

Now with XSLT I am trying to output the following `for-each` statement:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ListA/item">
    <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/> <xsl:value-of select="ListB/item"/>
    </li>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The problem lies within using the items of ListB. If I use this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ListA/item">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </li>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

I will get the output:

```
<li> Test 1 </li>
<li> Test 2 </li>
<li> Test 3 </li>
```

But I do not know how I could use both lists inside a for-each. Can anyone help 
me?

-- Edit --
The expected output that I want is:

```
<li> Test 1 100</li>
<li> Test 2 200</li>
<li> Test 3 300</li>
```

Comment: Please show your expected output.

Comment: @Utkanos yep good one. Added!

Comment: Use a [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key) to get the corresponding item from ListB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0 I would use keys. The idea is that you should index items in the ListB for a quick lookup.

Input:

```
<root>
  <ListA>
    <item index="0">Test 1</item>
    <item index="1">Test 2</item>
    <item index="2">Test 3</item>
  </ListA>
  <ListB>
    <item index="0">100</item>
    <item index="1">200</item>
    <item index="2">300</item>
  </ListB>
</root>
```

Stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:key name="list_b" match="/root/ListB/item" use="@index"/>

  <xsl:template match="ListA">
    <ul><xsl:apply-templates/></ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ListA/item">
    <li>
        <xsl:apply-templates /> - <xsl:text />
        <xsl:value-of select="key('list_b', @index)" />            
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `xsl:merge` in [XSLT 3.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#merge-instruction) as supported by Saxon 9.8 (all editions) or a current version of Altova XMLSpy/Raptor you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Root">
        <ul>
            <xsl:merge>
                <xsl:merge-source for-each-item="ListA, ListB" select="item">
                    <xsl:merge-key select="@index"></xsl:merge-key>
                </xsl:merge-source>
                <xsl:merge-action>
                    <li>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current-merge-group()"/>
                    </li>
                </xsl:merge-action>
            </xsl:merge>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which transforms

```
<Root>
    <ListA>
        <item index="0">Test 1</item>
        <item index="1">Test 2</item>
        <item index="2">Test 3</item>
    </ListA>
    <ListB>
        <item index="0">100</item>
        <item index="1">200</item>
        <item index="2">300</item>
    </ListB>
</Root>
```

into

```
<ul>
   <li>Test 1 100</li>
   <li>Test 2 200</li>
   <li>Test 3 300</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="ListA">
   <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
   </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="../../ListB/item[@index=current()/@index]"/>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

for use in simple foreach

```
<xsl:for-each select="ListA/item">
  <li>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="../../ListB/item[@index=current()/@index]"/>
  </li>
</xsl:for-each>
```